# How to use C++ lambda functions to map string to vector<int>?

Tags: c++, lambda

I want to achieve the transformation by using a lambda function

```
std::string str= "1 2 3";
std::vector<int> result = []()->{}; // result = {1, 2, 3}
```

Comment: Why particularly a lambda? A simple foreach with proper filters is way more efficient!

Comment: If you can come up with a non-lambda function solution, you can then just move that solution into a lambda function. The lambda function requirement is a trivial detail.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen I never said 'use a function'.

Comment: @Yksisarvinen not to mention std::for_each needs a lambda lol

Comment: Dimitar: Didn't the answer you got help you to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

Your code wont be compiled, if you want to initialize a variable with lambda :

```cpp
using vec_string_t = std::vector<std::string>;

auto  initializer = [](const std::string &sample)
  {
    vec_string_t  result;
    std::stringstream  stream(sample);

    for (std::string i; stream >> i; )
    {
      result.push_back(i);
    }

    return result;
  };

const auto  test = initializer("1 2 3");

for (const auto &item : test)
{
  std::clog << item << std::endl;
}
```

Require header file: `string`, `iostream`, `vector` and `sstream`.